# Golang Attach Struct into a JSON RawMessage

Tags: json, go, struct, slice

I have defined a struct like this:

```
type components struct {
    Value  string `json:"value"`
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

I have for loop go over the entire table, for a `component` column, I unmarshal it and pass value, ID, to do transformation function and get the result back.

```
for i := range table{
    var component []*components
    if err := json.Unmarshal(table[i].Components, &component); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range component {
        if _, ok := map[v.ID+"-"+v.Val]; ok {
            val2,ID2,err:= transformation(v.ID, v.Val) 
            if err != nil{
                log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err,"unrolling raw metric and raw machine error"))
            }
            v.Val = val2
            v.Name = val2
            v.ID = ID2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I call the transformation function, it returns some expected values. Instead of just replace the value, I would need to attach all return val to the component. Something like:

```
for i := range table{
    var component []*components
    if err := json.Unmarshal(table[i].Components, &component); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

for _, v := range component {
    if _, ok := map[v.ID+"-"+v.Val]; ok {
        res,err:= transformation(v.ID, v.Val) 

        //res is a component struct slice like ***var res []components*** and it contains multiple items

        if err != nil{
            log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err,"unrolling raw metric and raw machine error"))
        }

        for i,s := range res{
            if i == 0{
                v.Val = s.Value
                v.Name = s.Name
                v.ID = s.ID
            }else{
                I would like to create a item for the component like {Name:s.Name,ID:s.ID,Val:v.Val} and attach to the component so I can have multiple items in the component
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

If you can help me with `else` clause. Basically is attach a struct to a json raw message as the title indicate.

Answer (score 0):

in the else just append:

```
component = append (component,&components_str{Val:s.Value,ID:s.UUID,Name:s.Name})
```